# Why is the Recent Badges section full of silver and gold badges but rarely bronze badges?

Tags: support, badges

In https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges there is the *Recent Badges* section.

It has a lot of silver and gold badges and sometimes also bronze. But the bronze badges are a lot easier to get, so why are there so few bronze badges in comparison to  silver and **even** gold badges?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1853/145673

Comment: but *some* Bronze badges do show up

Comment: I am not sure as I don't see any bronze badges, but perhaps those are tag badges (e.g. when you get 100 score in python) which are *not* as easy to get?

Comment: @ZaidAlShattle The only one I saw is [Autobiographer] badge

Comment: Well, I cannot find any, but in that case I am not sure of the reason to be completely honest. I did notice a number of badges come in waves, and that might have something to do with it; but I will leave it to someone with more knowledge in the website's working to answer that I suppose

Comment: Perhaps the view has a fixed amount of badges and pick the rarest ones for display?